# Rails not updating record and shows no errors even when I know there is at least one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

**model**

```
class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_length_of :description, maximum: 160
end
```

**controller**

```
  def update
    @clip = @film.clips.find_by_permalink(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @clip.update(clip_params)
        format.html { redirect_to saas_admin_studio_film_path(@studio, @film), notice: 'Clip was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @clip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**view**

```
<%= render 'saas_admin/shared/errors', resource: resource %>
```

`<%= resource %>` generates `#<Clip:0x0000010c6c64e0>` so resource is loaded. However, `<%= resource.errors.any? %>` returns `false`. If I change in controller `@clip.update(clip_params)` to `@clip.update!(clip_params)` I get:

`Validation failed: Description is too long (maximum is 160 characters)`

So the validation works, it's just that it's not taken by `.errors` to display it.

**_errors**

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
    <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `resource` is the same Clip object as `@clip`.

Where in the code are you assigning `@clip` to be `resource`? I can't see where you have defined `resource` at all.

If you change it to be `<%= render 'saas_admin/shared/errors', resource: @clip %>` does the problem resolve?

Comment: You are so right, this app was using inherited_resources and therefore `resource` in `edit/update` actions was different to the one loaded by me in `update`. So to make my self clear, `resource` and `@clip` are 2 different objects.. My silly mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, though it probably seems backwards, the main difference between update and update! is how failed saves are handled.

When updating an ActiveRecord class the ! version will raise an exception if the record is invalid.

More info at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: Hi Michael, I know the difference between using `!` sign, the question is, if using `!` sign raises exception and validation error, why without it `resource.errors` is nil?

Comment: Sorry, I must be misunderstanding then.  If it takes ! to raise the exception then not using it would seem to lead to `resource.errors` being `nil` making sense.  So I must be missing something. apologies

Comment: It happens Michael, you helped me a few times anyway.. thank you.